# Creating a toString Method for a game representing a 1D grid in 2D

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to view my 1D array as a 2D array in a game of tic tac toe. However in my grid i only view the first element (element [0])in all 9 spaces.

This is my code:

```
public String toString() {
   StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
   int maxRowsIndex = game.numRows - 1;
   int maxColumnsIndex = game.numColumns - 1;

   String lineSeparator = Utils.repeat("---", game.numColumns) + Utils.repeat("-", game.numColumns - 1);

   b.append("POSITION: " + currentPosition + "(ODDS: "+ totalOdds +")\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < game.numRows; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < game.numColumns; j++) {
       int index = i*game.numColumns + j;

       b.append(" ");
       b.append(toString(index));
       b.append(" ");

       if (j < maxColumnsIndex) {
         b.append("|");
       }
     }

     // Line separator after each row, except the last
     if (i < maxRowsIndex) {
       b.append("\n");
       b.append(lineSeparator);
       b.append("\n");
     }
   }

   return b.toString();
 }

 private String toString(int index) {
   
   //int lookupIndex = game.boardIndexes[index];
   for(int i =0; i<game.board.length; i++){
   if (game.board[i] == CellValue.EMPTY){
       return boardOdds[i] + "";
   }
   else {
     return game.board[i] + "";
   }
 }
 return "";
}
```

**CellValue** has 3 options, X O or EMPTY

**game** represents an ongoing game of Tic Tac Toe

**board** is the array for the game board that has the CellValues

**boardOdds** is the array I'm trying to show in my toString method, but only in the board spots that are EMPTY, if they are full they should show X or O, as of right now, i get the first value of boardOdds repeated if the slot is EMPTY(boardOdds[0]). If the slot is not empty it gives me the board[0] (either X or O).

if it is EMPTY (i.e. board[0] == CellValue.EMPTY) i would like to see the boardOdds Value. If it is not EMPTY, I would like to see the board value (X or O).

the current issue is the i++ in my 2nd toString method **(private String toString(int index))** is never reached.

The Output looks like:

```
POSITION: 4[(ODDS: 31)
 8 | 8 | 8 
-----------
 8 | 8 | 8 
-----------
 8 | 8 | 8]
```

It should be :

```
POSITION: 4[(ODDS: 31)
 8 | 8 | 4 
-----------
 4 | 2 | 2 
-----------
 1 | 1 | 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> the current issue is the i++ in my 2nd toString method (private String
> toString(int index)) is never reached.

That is because you use `return` inside the for-loop, so only one iteration will be done. You can use a `StringBuilder` to generate your string:

```
private String toString(int index) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < game.board.length; i++) {
        if (game.board[i] == CellValue.EMPTY) {
            sb.append(boardOdds[i] + "");
        } else {
            sb.append(game.board[i] + "");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```